# I have 3 controllers getting list of data from DB and show it on dropdown list, but when it is selected it doesn't get the selected value of the list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this one is main controller and module of page

```
var bookinsert = angular.module('bookinsert', ['ngCookies']);
bookinsert.controller('book_insert_ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookies) {

$scope.func = function () {
    var writer = $scope.writer, title = $scope.title, genre = $scope.genre, language = $scope.lang, category=$scope.categ, publisher = $scope.publisher, publish_date = $scope.publish_date, isbn = $scope.isbn, page_count = $scope.page_count, cost = $scope.cost, books_instock = $scope.books_instock,review = $scope.review,book_image_1 = $scope.book_image_1,book_image_2 = $scope.book_image_2,book_image_3 = $scope.book_image_3,user_id = $cookies.get('user_id_cook');

    var book_info = {
        writer: writer,
        book_title: title,
        book_genre: genre,
        book_language: language,
        book_category: category,
        book_publisher: publisher,
        book_publishDate: publish_date,
        book_image_3: book_image,
        user_id: user_id
    };
    $http.post(insert_book_uri, book_info)
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log("Succed Inserting Book:");
            console.log(response);
        }) 
        .error(function (response) {
            console.log("Error on insertion: ");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(user_id);
        });
          };
       });
```

from now on all the controllers are just for retrieving list of data from DB. And i think it is the problem of angular scopes

```
bookinsert.controller('lang_ctrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
$http.post(lang_select_uri)
    .success(function (language_resp) {
        $rootScope.languages = language_resp;
        console.log("--Success--");
        console.log(language_resp);
    })
    .error(function () {
        console.log("error on language selection");
    });
});
```

**Image of the Drop down list is as below** 
[image]

Comment: whats the exact issue,are you getting the data from the api call or not ? do post your html as well for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bro you are doing it all wrong. First you should use services to hold or fetch data for you using $http. Controller should only be used to control views. And secondly you should assign language_resp to $scope variable and use that variable in view to reflect.

Comment: yes, agreed for saying that services should be created and then from there the web api should be called.

Comment: yes, I have service, **insert_book_uri** is the service url name stored in other file. Then, how can i get a list of data from database without controller?

Comment: thanks man, I did all the posts from one controller, and the problem solved :) (y)